# SendInput mouse time

Tags: c++, winapi, mousemove, smoothing, sendinput

So basically what I'm trying to do is move my mouse smoothly to the center.
What I have here works fine, but it teleports the cursor instantly to the center.

Also if I set `input.mi.time` to a value larger than 0, it puts my PC to sleep. Can anyone explain a bit more on what it even does? The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273.aspx) didn't really clarify it for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int screenWidth;
int screenHeight;

void moveMouse(int x, int y)
{
    POINT mouseCoords;
    GetCursorPos(&mouseCoords);

    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
    input.mi.dwExtraInfo = NULL;
    input.mi.mouseData = NULL;
    input.mi.dx = -mouseCoords.x + x;
    input.mi.dy = -mouseCoords.y + y;
    input.mi.time = NULL;

    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
}

void main()
{
    screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    int middleOfScreenX = screenWidth / 2;
    int middleOfScreenY = screenHeight / 2;

    moveMouse(middleOfScreenX, middleOfScreenY);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're experiencing the exact same issue as described in a 2012 posting by Raymond Chen:

[When you synthesize input with SendInput, you are also synthesizing the timestamp](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121101-00/?p=6193) (emphasis is mine):

> A customer was reporting a problem when they used the Send­Input function to simulate a drag/drop operation for automated testing purposes.
>
> Well, yeah, all the events occur immediately because you submitted them all at once.
>
> **The `time` field in the `MOUSE­INPUT` structure is not for introducing delays in playback**.

The solution is in the posting too:

> If you want three input events to take place with a 500ms delay between them, then you need to call Send­Input three times, with a 500ms delay between the calls.